# How can I change cursor style in InputField?

Tags: gui-construction

I want to make an `InputField` with a horizontal cursor, like this:

[image]

Note that the blinking cursor should be horizontal and not the mouse pointer! Nevertheless, text input should still be horizontal and not vertical.
The code below shows an `InputField` with the standard vertical cursor but I want a horizontal one.

```
x = Null;
Style[InputField[Dynamic[x], ImageSize -> {180, 60}, Alignment -> Center], Bold, 20]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `Rotate[Style[InputField[Dynamic[x], ImageSize -> {180, 60}, Alignment -> Center],Bold, 20], Pi/2]`.

Comment: @cormullion Thanks for the answer,that was great ! however I  am trying to get a horizontal `inputfield` as well as a horizontal cursor.

Comment: I think this works. `x = Null; l = Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {.07, 0}}]}];
MouseAppearance[
 Style[InputField[Dynamic[x], ImageSize -> {180, 60}, 
   Alignment -> Center], Bold, 20], l]`

Comment: Or perhaps I'm still misunderstanding and the blinking cursor for text should be horizontal?

Comment: @Ajasja I want `horizontal` cursor with in `InputField` not mousePointer.

Comment: Hmm, interesting question then. Don't know the answer.

Comment: Why don't you adapt cormullion's answer to `Rotate[Style[
  InputField[Dynamic[x], ImageSize -> {60, 180}, Alignment -> Center],Bold, 20], Pi/2]`?

Comment: @partial81 I want horizontal `inputField` as well as horizontal `cursor`,but he did vertical `inputfield`

Comment: If you use my code (which is almost the same code as @cormullion's), you will get this - at least you get as output something which is as in your picture above. If this is not the desired output, you should change this picture.