# Is it possible to change the text cursor's shape and color?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization

I find it visually pleasant to reverse the background and foreground colors when working on a notebook; as shown below, in fact, it's almost a requirement after working long hours on the same notebook.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  Background -> RGBColor[0.0, 0.0, 0.075], FontColor -> White
];
```

However this has the disadvantage of making the text cursor (not mouse pointer) very difficult to see, I couldn't find any documented option to change its shape or color, is there any option that allows this?

Comment: related: [55126](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55126/5478), [19175](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19175/5478)